# Casting array process in Java? (covariance and [LObject)

Tags: java, arrays, covariance

My question is how is the casting process in Java exactly?
suppose we have

```
User[] users = new User[2];//<-- here we get at runtime [LUser class
Object[] objects = (Object[]) users;//<-- here we get at runtime [LObject class

public class [LUser extends Object implements Serializable, Cloneable{

}

public class [LObject extends Object implements Serializable, Cloneable{

}
```

I know that because of arrays covariance as User is Object , User[] is Object[] as well. But explanation about class creation([LUser and [LObject issue) is damaging my understanding of covariance. Because if we notice [LUser and [LObject

```
User[] users = new User[2];
Object[] objects = (Object[]) users;
//<-- here we cast [LUser to [LObject but [LUser doesn't extends [Lobject
```

So how actually is going casting process?
May be questions seems crazy but logically I got this result. At worst case I can think that syntatically Java cast User[] to Object[] but at that time why we need object creation like [LObject, [LUser

Comment: "here we get at runtime [LObject class" What do you mean "get"? Casting doesn't change the type of the object: `users` is still concretely a `User[]`, so `objects` is concretely a `User[]` too.

Comment: Arrays are special. They're not classes like any other class. They have specific rules determining their behavior. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - Is it possible to subclass an array? And more questions about arrays in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9521117/java-is-it-possible-to-subclass-an-array-and-more-questions-about-arrays-in-j)

Comment: @AndyTurner we say 2 thoughts: 1 is objects var is User[] and also we say User array declaration means at runtime creating of object [LUser. so at the end User[] is User[] or [LUser? if you print users.getClass().getName() you will see [LUser.
If I cast User[] to Object[] it means I cast [Luser type to [LObject. Please try to understand my question. It is not simple as you thought

Comment: @Sarkhan I really have no idea what you are asking. [This simple example](https://ideone.com/T7d8Mc) shows that casting doesn't change the concrete type.

Comment: @JBNizet if you are clear enough about my question please write some deep explanation about it as you understood from specification. My exact question is here we cast [LUser to [LObject which [LUser doesn't extend [LObject. How it is possible?

Comment: @AndyTurner I am not changing concrete type. Let me ask one simple question.
Could you tell me users exact type? User[] or [LUser.And why?

Comment: @Sarkhan `[LUser` is simply what the JVM calls the concrete type `User[]`. It's the same thing.

Comment: @AndyTurner so Object[] is just Object[] and User[] or [LUser doesn't extends Object[] or [LObject right?  it is downcasting or upcasting? Where is the role of Object[] in User[]([LUser) class?

Comment: User[] **does** extend Object[]. As shown in the link I posted.

Comment: @JBNizet you say User[] extends Object[] but [LUser extends directly Object not Object[] or [LObject. As I print extended class of array I don't see in super classes Object[] or [Lobject

Comment: @JBNizet User[] users = new User[2]; System.out.println( users.getClass().getSuperclass().getName()); it prints only Object

Comment: Your cast is unnecessary. You can just write `Object[] objects = users;` since a User[] **is an** Object[]. Just like you can do `Fruit f = banana;`. And again, a cast only consists in checking that the object being casted is an instance of the tye is being cast to. The cast succeeds, because a User[] is an instance of Object[], as the specifications show.

Comment: @Sarkhan but, as I said in my first comment, arrays don't work like normal classes. They have specific rules that apply only to them. A String array is an instance of String[] but also an instance of CharSequence[], and also an instance of Serializable[], and also an instance of Cloneable[], and also an instance of Object[]. That can't happen with regular classes which can only have one superclass. Only with arrays.

Comment: @JBNizet I understand that specification says User[] extends Object[] but in practice as I print why it doesn't show me [LObject or Object[]?

Comment: And I think question is not same as others and must be stay, here logic is different, downvoting and close voting is not right at this situation

Comment: @JBNizet could you answer my last question?
 I understand that specification says User[] extends Object[] but in practice as I print why it doesn't show me [LObject or Object[]?

Comment: I have already answered. Read my previous comment. An array has several superclasses, and getSuperClass() can only return one, because the method has been designed to be used on regular classes, not on arrays, which have special rules, difference than those of regular classes.

Comment: @JBNizet when I declare User[] users= new User[2]; does Java create a class at runtime [LUser or JVM just understand User[] like [LUser but in each case new class must be created otherwise which classes object is creating?

Comment: @Sarkhan The `Class` of an array type is dynamically created at runtime by the JVM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [JLS 4.10.3. Subtyping among Array Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.3) *(link [provided by JB Nizet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51432559/casting-array-process-in-java-covariance-and-lobject#comment89836070_51432559))*:

> The following rules define the direct supertype relation among array types:
>
> - If `S` and `T` are both reference types, then `S[]` ><sub>1</sub> `T[]` iff `S` ><sub>1</sub> `T`.
> - `Object` ><sub>1</sub> `Object[]`
> - `Cloneable` ><sub>1</sub> `Object[]`
> - `java.io.Serializable` ><sub>1</sub> `Object[]`

The above means the following. Of course you can't write that, but that is the Java equivalent of the array subtyping rules.

```
//                     Rule #2           Rule #3    Rule #4
class Object[] extends Object implements Cloneable, Serializable {
}

//                   Rule #1
class User[] extends Object[] {
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

In addition, [JLS 10.7. Array Members](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.7) says:

> The members of an array type are all of the following:
>
> - The `public` `final` field `length`, which contains the number of components of the array. `length` may be positive or zero.
> - The `public` method `clone`, which overrides the method of the same name in class `Object` and throws no checked exceptions. The return type of the `clone` method of an array type `T[]` is `T[]`.
>
>   A clone of a multidimensional array is shallow, which is to say that it creates only a single new array. Subarrays are shared.
> - All the members inherited from class `Object`; the only method of `Object` that is not inherited is its `clone` method.

That then means:

```
class Object[] extends Object implements Cloneable, Serializable {
    public final int length = /*value from array creation*/;
    public Object[] clone() {
        try {
            return (Object[]) super.clone();
        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
            throw new InternalError(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

class User[] extends Object[] {
    public User[] clone() {
        return (User[]) super.clone();
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer is what I want to get!